When I launched Flutter application in VS-Code I got this error
When I launched the application I got this error.
Launching lib/main.dart on iphone 15 pro in debug mode... 
Running Xcode build...                                                    
└─Compiling, linking and signing...                         9,4s 
Xcode build done.                                           36,5s 
FFmpegKitFlutterPlugin 0x60000024b6e0 created. Connecting to the VM Service is taking longer than expected... Still attempting to connect to the VM Service... 
If you do NOT see the Flutter application running, it might have crashed. The device logs (e.g. from adb or XCode) might have more details. 
If you do see the Flutter application running on the device, try re-running with --host-vmservice-port to use a specific port known to be available. 
Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 57364 This was attempt #50. Will retry in 0:00:01.600000. Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 57429 This was attempt #100. Will retry in 0:00:01.600000. Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 57480 This was attempt #150. Will retry in 0:00:01.600000. FFmpegKitFlutterPlugin 0x60000022b600 created. Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 57548 This was attempt #200. Will retry in 0:00:01.600000. Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 57601 This was attempt #250. Will retry in 0:00:01.600000.

Incident Identifier: 344F78C3-E3BF-400A-AE76-759C5B33AF6C
CrashReporter Key:   323C7BED-0B9E-DB11-9F22-448164A6CA0A
Hardware Model:      MacBookAir10,1
Process:             Runner [16290]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4F362091-DC33-4F15-91DD-8EB6D1F63DC5/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6786C2CA-9B1A-417D-A6F5-272D22D29999/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:          kz.videopokaz.videopokazApp
Version:             1.0.0 (1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [93290]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4F362091-DC33-4F15-91DD-8EB6D1F63DC5 [28527]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [1095]

Date/Time:           2024-09-05 02:23:55.9044 +0500
Launch Time:         2024-09-05 02:23:54.5494 +0500
OS Version:          macOS 14.6.1 (23G93)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: Runner [16290]

Triggered by Thread:  0


Please help me. When I run flutter run, I see this error...

I don't work with flutter but after a quick research I found this, maybe this'll help you:

I solved the issue by changing a folder I created inside Runner folder.
I named it Resources and seems like xcode did not like it. Once I renamed to to anything else it worked

